# Jquery Ajax send tinyMCE html to php page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

Hey all i seem to be having problems with getting the full HTML code from the tinyMCE box when sending over to my PHP page to save to the database.

My Ajax code is this:

```
console.log('type=' + theType + '&rID=' + theReplyID + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&name=' + $('#name').val() + '&fb=' + FB + '&com=' + tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "post.php",
        cache: false,
        data: 'type=' + theType + '&rID=' + theReplyID + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&name=' + $('#name').val() + '&fb=' + FB + '&com=' + tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(),
        success: function(data,status){         
            showMsgBox('Your comment has been posted!','OK','blue');
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err){
            showMsgBox('Error while saving comment data','OK','red');
        }
    });
```

The **console.log** outputs the correct test data:

```
type=C&rID=&email=test@here.com&name=david dev&fb=na&com=<p>this is just a test&nbsp;    </p>
<p>here&nbsp;</p>
<p>and here</p>
```

But when it saves it to my database it only has:

```
<p>this is just a test
```

My PHP page looks like this:

```
<?PHP
   $type = $_POST['type']; //R(reply) or C(comment)
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $fb = $_POST['fb'];
   $comment = $_POST['com'];

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Gvth") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE Email = '" . $email . "'");  
$count = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $count++;       
    $id = $row["id"];
}

mysql_close($dbhandle);

   $dbhandle = mysql_connect("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("Gvth") or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO UserComments (UserInfoID,Comment,ImageUploaded,commentID,accepted,dt) 
    VALUES (" . $id . ",'" . $comment . "','na'," . $id . random_numbers(4) . ",1,'" . date('Y-m-d g:i:s',time()) . "');");
    mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

Comment: first of all... the mysql_* functions are deprecated use pdo or mysqli.
second escape your values  (if you keep using the deprecated functions use mysql_real_escape_string($comment)
 and how big is your comment field in your database table

Comment: @Miguelo the field is set to **LONGTEXT**

Comment: ok what happens if you put mysql_real_escape_string around all your variables in your query

Comment: @Miguelo using **mysql_real_escape_string($comment)** does not seem to help the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to create your querystring by hand (which i don't recommend), you will have to make sure al special chars like & are url-encoded. You can do this with `encodeURIComponent`.

So please change

```
data: 'type=' + theType + '&rID=' + theReplyID + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&name=' + $('#name').val() + '&fb=' + FB + '&com=' + tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(),
```

to

```
 data: 'type=' + theType + '&rID=' + theReplyID + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&name=' + $('#name').val() + '&fb=' + FB + '&com=' + encodeURIComponent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()),
```

An even better way to pass data with jQuery post is to pass an object to data instead of a querystring. Like so:

```
data: {type: theType, rID: theReplyID, email: $('#email').val(), name: $('#name').val(), com: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() },
```

This way, you won't need to escape any special characters.

Also, on the server side (in your PHP script) you should always escape user-posted data before inserting it to your database, with `mysql_real_escape_string()` like Miguelo mentioned.

Comment: You got it, Jules. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to all of the form data you want to use. Something like .formdata

Then, you can do this in place of the written out object:

```
$('.formdata').serialize();
```

That will create the object for you.

As for working with tinyMCE, I used to use this before I attempted to save the data.

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```